# design web application which consume many web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

problem is existing applications on our organization required to enter same data  multiple times, data naming conversions not consistent across applications.

currently there are many WCF and asmx web services already deployed for existing applications. But I don't have control over any of those services and also they are host on different countries. I can request small modifications for existing application (e.g. link to new application with required quarry strings.)

To overcome repetitive data entering process I have to find solution. currently what in my mind is create web application and keep business logic layer with reference to all required services.
need to request to do some modifications on existing applications to connect new application and it will map required data and made the connection between separated applications.

following are few questions currently facing,

1. To do a task there may be many
   services required, if one service
   not respond on middle of the process
   how I can rollback the process ?
2. since all are service calls it may
   take more time to do a simple
   operation but i need to increase
   performance of the applications, how
   I can improve performance while
   handling many services on one
   application?

Comment: Wow! Such clear requirements. What else does one need to design an application!!

Comment: Sounds like you're not truly separating business logic with interface if you're relying on multiple sources for a complete response. I'd recommend either revamping your architecture to the traditional 3-tier system, or develop a middle tier (staging platform) that does all the running around if refactoring/redeveloping is not an option.

Comment: It kind of sounds like he is trying to call services that aren't under his control - an example might be, his application allows people to update their status - which then updates facebook, twitter, my[_____], etc. So the services aren't his, but he wants to call them all. To top it off they sound unreliable? It's unclear though

Comment: This sounds to vague to give clear and usable answers imho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools such as Biztalk might fit for your scenario, depending on your architecture and integration options. See http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/default.aspx.

edit: 
as per your edit with your additional questions:

1. if you are storing results to your local database, you should be able to do a database rollback if any of the service calls fail. If the service calls will span a long duration of time, so that this cannot happen in the context of a single session, then you can create a holding area of sort in your data model. The holding area can hold all of the results from your various service calls. If all succeed, you can then transfer the holding area to your permanent storage. If all fail, you can rollback your holding area data.
2. One way to to improve user responsiveness in this type of scenario is to asynchronously call your web services. This may require a page redesign, since the user's browser page will receive its response even if all service calls haven't completed. But if you have no control over the services and must call them, this is probably your only option to improve user responsiveness

Comment: good point Shan, but I can't go for Biztalk now, have find a way from ASP.net.

Comment: as per your answers, if i maintain local database with logs may help me to complete transactions ones service up again, and also AJAX is one technology I can use to improve performance and user interaction. isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, a local database with logs (I just called that a holding area). You could store the service results. It would be a durable way to design your solution. The effort could be significant depending on your requirements, i.e. if a service fails, will you then attempt to call the service in 5 minutes time, or an hour time, etc. AJAX is definitely one way that could improve user response times, versus a standard ASPX asynchronous web page. Either way, going asynchronously is the way to improve perceived responsiveness.